# Autodesk's Fbx Python and threading

Tags: python, multithreading, autodesk, fbx

I'm trying to use the fbx python module from autodesk, but it seems I can't thread any operation. This seems due to the GIL not relased. Has anyone found the same issue or am I doing something wrong? When I say it doesn't work, I mean the code doesn't release the thread and I'm not be able to do anything else, while the fbx code is running.

There isn't much of code to post, just to know whether it did happen to anyone to try.

Update:

here is the example code, please note each fbx file is something like 2GB

```
import os
import fbx
import threading

file_dir = r'../fbxfiles'


def parse_fbx(filepath):
    print '-' * (len(filepath) + 9)
    print 'parsing:', filepath

    manager = fbx.FbxManager.Create()
    importer = fbx.FbxImporter.Create(manager, '')
    status = importer.Initialize(filepath)
    if not status:
        raise IOError()

    scene = fbx.FbxScene.Create(manager, '')
    importer.Import(scene)
    # freeup memory
    rootNode = scene.GetRootNode()

    def traverse(node):
        print node.GetName()

        for i in range(0, node.GetChildCount()):
            child = node.GetChild(i)
            traverse(child)

    # RUN
    traverse(rootNode)
    importer.Destroy()
    manager.Destroy()


files = os.listdir(file_dir)
tt = []

for file_ in files:
    filepath = os.path.join(file_dir, file_)
    t = threading.Thread(target=parse_fbx, args=(filepath,))
    tt.append(t)
    t.start()
```

Comment: Please also share the code, which doesn't release the thread. You will get better response. Right now we won't even have a idea regarding what your are doing or trying to achieve

Comment: The interpreter actually never concurrently executes Python code because of the GIL. The GIL is generally only released when I/O takes place and the current thread is waiting for it to complete. While that going on, any waiting threads will be given a chance to run. So your problem may have nothing to do with the fact that you're using the fbx module.

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri, example code has been uploaded.

Comment: @martineau, thanks please have a look at the code I posted.

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is with your `traverse()` function. It's calling itself recursively potentially a huge number of times. Another is having all the threads printing stuff at the same time. Doing that properly requires coordinating access to the shared output device (i.e. the screen). A simple way to do that is by creating and using a global `threading.Lock` object.

First create a global `Lock` to prevent threads from printing at same time:

```
file_dir = '../fbxfiles'  # an "r" prefix needed only when path contains backslashes
print_lock = threading.Lock()  # add this here
```

Then make a non-recursive version of `traverse()` that uses it:

```
    def traverse(rootNode):
        with print_lock:
            print rootNode.GetName()

        for i in range(node.GetChildCount()):
            child = node.GetChild(i)
            with print_lock:
                print child.GetName()
```

It's not clear to me exactly where the reading of each fbxfile takes place. If it all happens as a result of the `importer.Import(scene)` call, then that is the only time any other threads will be given a chance to run — unless some I/O is [also] done within the `traverse()` function.

Since printing is most definitely a form of output, thread switching will also be able to occur when it's done. However, if all the function did was perform computations of some kind, no multi-threading would take place within it during its execution.

Once you get the multi-reading working, you may encounter insufficient memory issues if multiple 2GB fbxfiles are being read into memory simultaneously by the various different threads.

Comment: Hi, prints as are just representative, the final result should be kept in memory somewhere and reported through a ui (qt).
Tried all sorts of things to make this work, but does not seems to be working as expected (did not tried locks as no O (of I/O) is happening).

Good point on the memory though.
need to get to a mid size fbx to try (~400/600Mb) or my machine blows up.
Cheers.

Comment: If there's no I/O, then there's no chance for multithreading to occur. Regardless you probably need to use a non-recursive version of `traverse()` because each nested call to itself uses up memory and Python has a maximum recursion depth allowed. If that is exceeded it will cause a `RuntimeError`. Also, if the final result is keep in memory, you'll need some way to control concurrent access to it from multiple threads (assuming you had code that would do some I or O and release the GIL so other threads could run).

Comment: Just thought of this approach: If your thread function doesn't do any I/O, you can force it to temporarily release the GIL, thereby giving other threads the opportunity to run, by calling `time.sleep()` periodically within the loop in `traverse()`.